# is a nil server message possible with gRPC?

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

In the following `gRPC`-client code, is the second `if` necessary?

```
status, err := cli.GetStatus(ctx, &empty.Empty{})
if err != nil {
    return err
}

if status == nil {
    // this should NEVER happen - right?
    return fmt.Errorf("nil Status result returned") 
}
```

Intuitively, one should always check for nil in `go` *just in case*.
However, there is a runtime check to catch any client-to-server `nil` usage e.g.

```
status, err := cli.GetStatus(ctx, nil) // <- runtime error

if err != nil {
    // "rpc error: code = Internal desc = grpc: error while marshaling: proto: Marshal called with nil"
    return err
}
```

So is there a similar server-to-client runtime guarantee, and thus remove the need for a `status == nil` check?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Investigating further with a contrived server example:

```
func (s *mygRPC) GetStatus(context.Context, *empty.Empty) (*pb.Status, error) {
    log.Println("cli: GetStatus()")

    //return &pb.Status{}, nil
    return nil, nil // <- can server return a nil status message (with nil error)
}
```

and testing client/server reactions:

**CLIENT:**

```
ERROR: rpc error: code = Internal desc = grpc: error while marshaling: proto: Marshal called with nil
```

**SERVER:**

```
2019/05/14 16:09:50 cli: GetStatus()
ERROR: 2019/05/14 16:09:50 grpc: server failed to encode response:  rpc error: code = Internal desc = grpc: error while marshaling: proto: Marshal called with nil
```

So even if one wanted to *legitimately* return a nil value, the `gRPC` transport will not allow it.

**Note:** the server-side code is still executed - as expected - but as far as the client is concerned, the `gRPC` call failed.

**Conclusion:** a valid (`err==nil`) server response will *always* return a valid (non-`nil`) message.

---

**EDIT:**

Inspecting the `gRPC` source reveals where a `nil` message is caught:

[server.go](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/server.go#L837)

```
func (s *Server) sendResponse(t transport.ServerTransport, stream *transport.Stream, msg interface{}, cp Compressor, opts *transport.Options, comp encoding.Compressor) error {
    data, err := encode(s.getCodec(stream.ContentSubtype()), msg)
    if err != nil {
        grpclog.Errorln("grpc: server failed to encode response: ", err)
        return err
    }
    // ...
}
```

[rpc_util.go](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/rpc_util.go#L543)

```
func encode(c baseCodec, msg interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
    if msg == nil { // NOTE: typed nils will not be caught by this check
        return nil, nil
    }
    b, err := c.Marshal(msg)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, status.Errorf(codes.Internal, "grpc: error while marshaling: %v", err.Error())
    }
    // ...
}
```

The comment in this line is key:

```
if msg == nil { // NOTE: typed nils will not be caught by this check }
```

So if one were to use reflect on our typed-nil, `reflect.ValueOf(msg).IsNil()` would return `true`. The following `c.Marshal(msg)` errors - and the call fails to send a message response to the client.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this should never happen. GRPC is responsible for that.

Comment: @colm.anseo does reflect.ValueOf(msg).IsNil() handle regular nil check as well?